# remove a sub regex query from a regex

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

I have a string which contains certain sequence "SMP-unknown number of characters-4 characters". I have to select everything from the string apart from the regex. At present I'm able to select the substring which is to be excluded.

`(SMP-([\S])+-[\S][\S][\S][\S])`

I have to select everything apart from the mentioned regex from a string.

Test string:

`"testing updated regex: SMP-werdgs-2903 testm"`

Comment: `s.match(/SMP-[^-\s]+-\S{4}/)[0]`?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do what you ask:

1/ Match everything before and after and do a join of both results:

```
  ^(.*) SMP-([\S])+-[\S][\S][\S][\S] (.*)$
```

or in javascript

```
  matches = p.match(/^(.*)SMP-\S+-\S{4}(.*)$/);
  result = matches[1]+matches[2];
  // or matches[0] seem to work also
```

2/ Use the regexp replace operator to remove the unwanted part from your string:

```
  s/SMP-([\S])+-[\S][\S][\S][\S]//$
```

or in javascript:

```
  result = p.replace(/SMP-\S+-\S{4}/ '')
```